# R equivalent of Pandas info(null_counts = True)?

Tags: r, pandas, null

Is there an R equivalent of .info(null_counts = True)?

I am interested in essentially printing each column name and how many null values are present in each column.

Comment: If you meant `NA`, then `colSums(is.na(df1))`

Answer (score 0):

Try with your data with `describe` of `Hmisc`

```
Hmisc::describe(z)
```